# Dump Accessibility Tree From Headless Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility

When running a headless Chrome process, the DOM can be sent to stdout with:

`google-chrome --headless --dump-dom https:/www.google.com`

Is there an equivalent option to dump out the accessibility tree?

If not, is there a way to programatically access the accessibility tree that doesn't require the GUI?

I have tried searching for documentation but have not managed to find anything.